# My code gives me numbers in the wrong order

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, range

I want to know the numbers between 100-1000 which have a cross sum of each digit ^3 that equals the number itself.

E.g.

```
3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371
```

My code gives me the numbers, but not ascending. What did I do wrong?

The code:

```
numbers=list(range(101,1000))  

for item in numbers:           
    sum=0                      
    sum2=""                    
    while item:                
            d=item%10          
            item=item//10      
            sum=(sum+d**3)     
            sum2=sum2+str(d)   
    if sum==int(sum2):         
        print(sum2)
```

Result:

```
371
153
407
```

Comment: Take a simple number like e. g. 17 as item and look what happens to sum2 with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the number you're iterating with the sum of the cubed digits instead:

```
numbers = list(range(101, 1000))
for item in numbers:
    sum = 0
    number = item
    while number:
        d = number % 10
        number = number // 10
        sum = (sum + d ** 3)
    if sum == item:
        print(item)
```

This outputs:

```
153
370
371
407
```

Comment: Many thanks !!! This solves my problem. To sum up, you put number=item before the while loop so that you have a second variable (number) that can change in the loop and at the same time have "item", which you ultimately compare "sum" with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple oneliner to solve your particular problem:

```
[n for n in range(101, 1000) if sum([int(v)**3 for v in list(str(n))]) == n]
```

Comment: I feel like I'm too dumb to understand your code. But I will look at it again once I get better at coding :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could do a much more simplified approach:

```
numbers=list(range(101,1000))  

for num in numbers:
    product = sum([int(x)**3 for x in str(num)])
    if product == num:
        print(num)
```

output:

```
153
370
371
407
```